# Django models - auto-increment id for elements of a child table for each parent reference

Tags: django, model, auto-increment

I'm trying structure the database of an app in Django that will have companies and projects. Each company can have many projects and each project will belong to only one company.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Project(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I'd like to have a field or a property in the model Project that acts like an auto-increment integer for the projects within a Company. The behaviour should be like the following:

```
c1 = Company(name="C1")
c2 = Company(name="C2")
px = Project(company=c1, name="X")
py = Project(company=c2, name="Y")
pz = Project(company=c1, name="Z")
px.project_id
1
py.project_id
1
pz.project_id
2
```

What would be the correct approach?

Comment: The `project_id` is a bad idea, that'll get confusing. You could use a property that combined the object `id` with a string of some sort? Or just use the `id` of `Project`?

Answer (score 5):

The most automatic way to accomplish this would be to customize the `save` method of your model, e.g.:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk == None:
            self.project_id = Project.objects \ 
                .filter(company=self.company) \
                .aggregate(max_id=Max("project_id")).get("max_id",0) + 1)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

You can read more about `save` in the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) and [in this blog post by Lincoln Loop](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/)

That being said, as noted by @markwalker_, you may find it a bit confusing to manage your projects with a secondary "id", given that you already get a natural sequential one that is unique for all projects. It might be worthwhile to identify your projects with a slug and start_date, and then you can easily identify them, create natural urls, etc, in combination with a company slug.

For example:

```
/company/acme-inc/2018/12/website-redesign/
```

vs

```
/company/acme-inc/project/4/
```

Comment: thanks @Nikolaj Baer, that's just what I was looking for. The idea is to have an 'internal_id' of the projects within a company, so each company can easily keep track of their own projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AutoField for auto incrementing:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=False) # set it as primary key if you want it to be
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I'm a little unclear on exactly what you're looking to do, but it seems like you want to keep track of how many projects each company has. In this case you could write a model function for Company that keeps track of how many:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    projects = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def get_project_count(self):
        project_count = Project.objects.filter(company=self).count()
        self.projects = project_count
        self.save()
        return self.projects
```